# I want to ask about save file excel after export in Reactjs and C#

Tags: c#, reactjs, excel, asp.net-core

I export excel like in this article: https://blog.elmah.io/export-data-to-excel-with-asp-net-core/ (using xlsx)

after that, in response I get the blob:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
return Post(API_CREATE_CSV_POST_PRIVATE, null, model, null, null)
 .then(res => {
  if (res.ok) {
    const file = new Blob(
      [res.value], 
      {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});

    saveAs(file, "baocao.xlsx");
```

But when I open excel, I get the error: Excel cannot open the file baocao.xlsx because the file format or file extensiion is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Can someone help me?

It appears that res.value is undefined but I dont know what I should pass into instead of res.value?

Here is my Post:

export function Post(
api,
param = null,
model,
header = null,
convertToJson = false,
) {
let API = api;
if (param && param.toString().length > 0) {
API = API + '/' + param;
}
return fetch(API, {
method: 'POST',
headers: Header('application/json', header),
body: JSON.stringify(model),
})
.then(res => {
if (convertToJson) {
if (res.ok) return res.json();
} else {
return res;
}
})
.catch(error => {
consoleLog(error);
return null;
});
}

Comment: This looks oke to me.. your problem might be in what the server is returning. I have a project with a similar setup and my backend returns a file stream with contentType: 'application/octet-stream'.

Comment: It appears that res.value is undefined but I dont know what I should pass into instead of res.value?

Comment: Well... what is res itself? What does the server send back?

Comment: Res is response, server send back I think is the file. In the link I post above it return to a file

Comment: Res is response. The server send back is a file as it is in the link I sent above. It return File

Answer (score 0):

> return File(
> content,
> "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
> "users.xlsx");

In the Api method, please check the above code, it will return a File object.

So, the easiest way to download the file is to add the following hyperlink, and directly call the API method:

```
<a href="~/api/Todo/exporttoexcel" download>Download File</a>
```

The API method as below:

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]  [ApiController]  public class ToDoController : ControllerBase  { 
     [HttpGet("exporttoexcel")]
     public async Task<ActionResult> ExportToExcel()
     {
         using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook())
         {
             var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Users");
             var currentRow = 1;
             worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = "Id";
             worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = "Username";
             var users = new List<User>();
             for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
             {
                 users.Add(new Models.User() { UserId = i, UserName = "User" + i.ToString() });
             }
             foreach (var user in users)
             {
                 currentRow++;
                 worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 1).Value = user.UserId;
                 worksheet.Cell(currentRow, 2).Value = user.UserName;
             }
             using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
             {
                 workbook.SaveAs(stream);
                 var content = stream.ToArray();
                 return File(
                     content,
                     "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
                     "users.xlsx");
             }
         }
     }
```